# ionic - wrong display of blinking caret/cursor when scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework

I am calling $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBy when focusing an input. the scroll works fine, but the cursor is displayed on the wrong place (displayed on the old place of the input before scrolling), and it stays there until start typing.

```
element.bind("focus", function(e){
    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBy(0, 100, true);
});
```

Please any help how to fix this.

Environment: 
ionic 1.3.0,
ios simulator (9.2) & iPad (9.2)